# Postgres function returning the number 0-7 round robin?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I write a function which returns for example the numbers 0-7 round robin, in a "thread safe" manner ensuring a new number for each call (wrap around if > 7)?

It should be a global function so if "connection 1" calls it and gets the number 3, "connection 2" should get the number 4 when it calls and so on.

Comment: just create  a sequece

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html), you can cycle sequence:

```
t=# create sequence rr07 minvalue 0 maxvalue 7 cycle;
CREATE SEQUENCE
t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       0
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       1
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       2
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       3
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       4
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       5
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       6
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       7
(1 row)

t=# select nextval('rr07');
 nextval
---------
       0
(1 row)
```